# extjs tree panel context menu not working

Tags: extjs

```
var menu1 = new Ext.menu.Menu({
    items: [{
        text: 'Open in new tab'

    }]
});
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'tree-panel',
    region: 'center',
    useArrows: true,
    singleExpand: true,
    split: false,
    height: 360,
    minSize: 150,
    rootVisible: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    store: store,
    border: false,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'text',
        flex: 2,
        sortable: true,
        displayField: true
    }]

});
treePanel.on('contextmenu', function(event, node) {
    alert(node)
    //treePanelCurrentNode = node;
    x = event.browserEvent.clientX;
    y = event.browserEvent.clientY;
    menu1.showAt([x, y]);
}, this);
```

Working on 4.1 ext js and trying to add context menu to this tree panel but menu is not working. In the tree panel store is coming 
but my code

```
treePanel.on('contextmenu', function(event,node){};
```

is not working 
 not event

```
treePanel.on('click', function(event,node){};
```

Any idea related to ext js context menu on tree panel ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tree doesn't have `contextmenu` event in ExtJS4.

You should use [`itemcontextmenu`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-itemcontextmenu) instead of `contextmenu`:

```
treePanel.on('itemcontextmenu', function(view, record, item, index, event) {
    alert(record)
    //treePanelCurrentNode = record;
    menu1.showAt(event.getXY());
    event.stopEvent();
}, this);
```

Comment: im trying to do the same, but this doesnt work properly, the menu is displayed but its covered with the browser default menu and the alert shows [object Object], thanks

Comment: @astrocybernaute, updated my answer(added `event.stopEvent` which prevents browser default menu from showing). Regarding to [object Object]: what does alert have to show? Alert shows object variables this way. Use console.log to see what is in record.

Answer (score 1):

When the data view is rendered it disabling the default right click web browser menu, this is called in listeners “render” event and “itemcontexmenu” event is for detecting right click mouse event, capture the mouse cursor position and displaying the menu.

```
  listeners: {


        render: function() {
             Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true});
        },
        itemcontextmenu : function( grid, record, item, index, event){
            x = event.browserEvent.clientX;
            y = event.browserEvent.clientY;

            menu1.showAt([x, y]);


        }
}
```