# ExtJS 4: context-menu (right-click) event on a tree.Panel node

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I added "contextmenu" entry to the list of listeners in treepanel, but it seems that it doesn't work. ExtJS doesn't give the control to my event handler function. I also supressed browser default context menu event beforehand, but it doesn't help either.

Any code examples? I haven't found any working samples for ExtJS 4. Am I missing something?

**Update 1:** my code

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'treePanel',  
    store: store,               
    renderTo: 'tree-div',
    height: 300,
    width: 250,
    title: 'OrgTree',
    useArrows: true,
    listeners: {                        
        render : {
            fn : function() {                            
                 Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true});
            }
        },                    
        contextmenu : {                     
            fn: function(node, evtObj) {
                alert('here');
            }
        },
    }
});
```

**Update 2:** this is the solution [extjs tree panel context menu not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792548/extjs-tree-panel-context-menu-not-working)

Comment: possible duplicate of [extjs tree panel context menu not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792548/extjs-tree-panel-context-menu-not-working)

Comment: yup, my post is a duplicate. please close it.

Comment: @AlphaSisyphus I've voted to close. Thanks for taking the time to dig up the answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extjs tree panel context menu not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792548/extjs-tree-panel-context-menu-not-working)